# filling empty values with current date in power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

i would like to fill empty cells in power query with the current date. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atHtV.png)

I bought an power query course but such problems are not mentioned in them, i tried also an if function but the result was that the other dates came out null and the before null rows became "true"...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add custom column with the following formula:

```
=if [YourDateColumn] = null then DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()) else [YourDateColumn]
```

All empty cells will be populated with your current system date. Please note that the date will calculate automatically and will change every day.

Hope that answers your question. If not then let me know in comments :)